# Random Partitioner behavior on the joined RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to join two data sets. One of type (Id, salesRecord) another (Id,Name).
First data-set is partitioned by HashPartitioner and Second is partitioned by Custom Partitioner. When I join these RDDs by id and try to see which partition-er information is retained I randomly see that some times joinRDD displays custom partitioner and sometimes HashPartitioner.  I received different partioner results while changing the number of partitions also.

According to the Learning Spark book, rdd1.join(rdd2) retains the partition info from the rdd1.

Here is the code.

```
  val hashPartitionedRDD = cusotmerIDSalesRecord.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10))
println("hashPartitionedRDD's partitioner " + hashPartitionedRDD.partitioner) // Seeing Instance of HashParitioner

val customPartitionedRDD = customerIdNamePair1.partitionBy(new CustomerPartitioner)
println("customPartitionedRDD partitioner " + customPartitionedRDD.partitioner) // Seeing instance of CustomPartitioner

val expectedHash = hashPartitionedRDD.join(customPartitionedRDD)
val expectedCustom = customPartitionedRDD.join(hashPartitionedRDD)

println("Expected Hash " + expectedHash.partitioner) // Seeing instance of Custom Partitioner
println("Expected Custom " + expectedCustom.partitioner) //Seeing instance of Custom Partitioner

// Just to add more to it when number of partitions of both the data sets I made equal I am seeing the reverse results. i.e. 
// expectedHash shows CustomPartitioner and 
// expectedCustom shows Hashpartitioner Instance.
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`join`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala) method internally calls, [`Partitioner.defaultPartitioner()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7a375bb87a8df56d9dde0c484e725e5c497a9876/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala) method.

Based on definition of `defaultPartitioner`:

```
def defaultPartitioner(rdd: RDD[_], others: RDD[_]*): Partitioner = {
    val bySize = (Seq(rdd) ++ others).sortBy(_.partitions.size).reverse
    for (r <- bySize if r.partitioner.isDefined && r.partitioner.get.numPartitions > 0) {
      return r.partitioner.get
    }
    if (rdd.context.conf.contains("spark.default.parallelism")) {
      new HashPartitioner(rdd.context.defaultParallelism)
    } else {
      new HashPartitioner(bySize.head.partitions.size)
    }
  }
}
```

If you look closely in line:

```
val bySize = (Seq(rdd) ++ others).sortBy(_.partitions.size).reverse
```

It starts the `for-loop` (or search) based on number of partitions in descending order. So if both `RDDs` have their own partitioners, the **one with higher number of partitions will be chosen**.

**EDIT**: The issue you raised about seeing `reverse` behavior is quite simple. Here, if both have same number of partitions, the `others` will come at the top of the `Seq`. So, the partitioner of the argument `RDD` will be chosen.

```
(Seq(rdd) ++ others).sortBy(_.partitions.size).reverse
```

This behavior is explainable, but perhaps not intuitive.

Comment: Thanks @Mohitt. Got you but when both the data sets have the same number of partitioner that time I am seeing reverse results