# How to reduce Spark task counts & avoid group by

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

All, I am using PySpark & need to join two RDD's but to join them both I need to group all elements of each RDD by the joining key and later perform a join function. This causes additional overheads and I am not sure what a work around can be. Also this is creating a high number of tasks that is in turn increasing the number of files to write to HDFS and slowing overall process by a lot here is a example:

```
RDD1 = [join_col,{All_Elements of RDD1}] #derived by using groupby join_col)
RDD2 = [join_col,{All_Elements of RDD2}] #derived by using groupby join_col)

RDD3 = RDD1.join(RDD2)
```

Comment: Is `(key, ([...],  [...]))` exact output you need?

Comment: just result of join is good - dont need key,data.

Comment: Join operations are usually costly. I had a recent discussion on improving the behavior on this threaD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508847/random-partitioner-behavior-on-the-joined-rdd/35509604#35509604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If desired output is grouped and both RDDs are to large to be broadcasted there is not much you can do at the code level. It could be cleaner to simply apply `cogroup`:

```
rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)
```

but there should be no significant difference performance-wise. If you suspect there can be a large data / hash skew you can try different partitioning, for example by using `sortByKey` but it is unlikely to help you in a general case.