# Spark Streaming: How to process using multiple inputs to job?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, stream, spark-streaming, flink-streaming

**Input 1:** stream of KV data.
**Input 2:** some static data partition (used to process stream in input 1)
Problem could be modelled as following image:
[image]
**Co-location with HDFS/RDD partition:** How can we ensure that the streaming tasks Map1, Map2 and Map3 run on machines where the HDFS/RDD partition is present? 
**Image description:** Assume **K** is a streamed key (not a tuple). First Map is converting it to a tuple (with a null value) and broadcast it to 3 Mappers. Each mapper is running on different node containing different partition of an RDD (or HDFS file, which is the second input and static Data). Each Mapper uses RDD partition to compute the value for the key. At last we want to aggregate value for the key (using reduceByKey _+_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

1. The `K` is the `RDD` you got from `***DStream` via `streaming` job. I do not know the source of your incoming data. This data is basically a `array/seq/list` of Keys.
2. The Static data you mentioned is a `PairedRDD` of the form `<K, Object>`. From the `Object`, you want to extract `Val_n` for the keys in the `incoming RDD`.
3. You are aiming to avoid/minimize the `shuffle` while this `join` (or lookup) process.

For this, the best strategy would be use a [`Join`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala) operation with `incoming RDD` and `Static RDD` with both RDDs `partitioned` using the same [`Partitioner`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7a375bb87a8df56d9dde0c484e725e5c497a9876/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala). In case either of the data RDD is much smaller than the other one, you can explore `broadcasting` the smaller one. I have recently tried this in my project and shared experience in the post: [Random Partitioner behavior on the joined RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508847/random-partitioner-behavior-on-the-joined-rdd/35509604)

**Edit**: Since you want to process your keys, `K` (assuming K=Set{K1, K2...Kn}), using `StaticRDD`, in place with the partition, I suggest an approach like below. I have not checked the syntax and correctness, but you will get the intent.

```
val kRddBroadcastVar = .... // broadcasted variable 
val keyValRDD = staticRDD.mapPartitions {   
       iter => transformKRddToTuple2Events(iter, kRddBroadcastVar )
     }

def transformKRddToTuple2Events( iter: Iterator[Object], kRddBroadcastVar: List[KeyObjectType] ) : Iterator[(keyObjectType, valueObjectType )] {    
     val staticList = iter.toList
     val toReturn   = kRddBroadcastVar.map ( k => getKeyValue(k, staticList) )    
     toReturn.iterator
}

val outRdd = keyValRDD.reduceByKey( _ + _ )
```

In case this make sense, mark this answer accepted.

Comment: Hi Mohit! Thanks for answering. I've tried to explain the image in the edit. Actually the input key K is to be broadcasted to all the mappers, so co-partitioning is not going to help. Secondly our static RDD may not contain tuples. But for evaluating value for input key we want to traverse the partition (in-memory). Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Hi Mohit! Thanks for editing your answer. Given me a lot of insights. I tried to broadcast a mutable collection of scala. Then used mapPartition on static RDD to manipulate local copy of broadcast variable. And it just worked! All nodes have different values for broadcast variable. Now I will try co-partitioning input stream and use broadcast variable instead of data partition. Will update you soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mohit! The thing I wanted to do, couldn't be done in the way I planned (last comment). Using the same partitioner, spark doesn't ensure the co-location of same partitions of different RDDs. It may be doing that for join, but doesn't do in general! My static data is not key-val. Each key in stream data is required to be processed using 2 complete scan of entire data. Thus when static data is divided in partitions (desired to be on different nodes), I want each key (from stream input) to be broadcast to all nodes having static data partition and do local scans. Any suggestions?

Comment: Same partitioner for two Rdds does not ensure co-location. Even for Join, spark can not ensure that. Anyways, since you do not intend to use join(and your data is not a <k,v> pair), there is no need to use any partitioner. Coming back to your question, if you have broadcasted your key-data, it will be available at all the nodes as a simple java variable. In other words, you have a copy of this variable available at all the nodes. Now, I had suggested for mapPartition method which takes  transformKRddToTuple2Events to make use of static and key-data to produce desired result at each partition.

Comment: let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Is your static RDD small enough to be cached. In that case Spark will try to run streaming tasks on those nodes. Its not guaranteed though.

Also if the reference data is of small size why don't you broadcast that data set.

We have been trying to solve similar issues regarding preferred locations in our data store SnappyData ( http://www.snappydata.io/) , where data location is first class citizen.

Comment: Thanks Rishitesh! Actually each key require multiple scans of data partition at Mapper1, Mapper2 and Mapper3. If we have complete data as broadcast variable, multiple scans could be time consuming. On smaller data(partition) multiple scan is less computation intensive. Actually for my use case (research work) Apache Samza suits better, but as I need to compare with other frameworks too.